# Finding the number of spanning trees on a set of vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I need to find the number of spanning trees on $V = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, where $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are leaves. Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work backwards. Erase the vertices $1,2,3,4$. Then, since all four are leaves, you get a spanning tree on $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$.

This spanning tree is a spanning tree of $K_5$, and the number of such spanning trees is well known. Now, add back the vertices $1,2,3,4$. Since they are leaves, each of them can be connected to one of $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$, and the choices are independent. Thus, for each of them you have exactly $5$ choices.

Comment: So the answer should be 5^3(due to cayley's formula) for K5, and I've got to multiply it with 5! since it's the options for placing the leaves?

Comment: @user3623042 you have $5^4$ for placing the leaves, note that you can place two leaves at the same vertex.